# Нужна ли запятая после перечисления

Tags: пунктуация

**Арест беременных женщин, имеющих на руках грудных детей, тяжелобольных() может быть временно отложен.**

Нужна ли запятая после перечисления?Интонационно здесь чувствуется пауза,но ставится ли знак препинания?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оснований для постановки запятой нет.